# Is it true that $ \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^n a_{n,i} = +\infty? $ when $a_{n,i}\to+\infty$?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, sequences-and-series

Let $a_{n,i} \in \mathbb{R}$ (they might be negative for some $n$ and $i$) for $i \in \{1, 2, \, ... , , n\}$ and $n$ growing to $\infty$ (I think the name for this structure is "triangular array"). Assume $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} a_{n,i} = + \infty$ for all $i$. Is it true that
$$
\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^n a_{n,i} = +\infty?
$$
It seems like it should be true, but I haven't been able to prove it as is...

For example, if I take $\min_{i \in 1:n} a_{n,i} = \ell_n$, then it's enough to show $\lim_{n \rightarrow +\infty} \ell_n = + \infty$. Now, I'm not sure how to justify that $\ell_n$ goes to $+\infty$. When I try to write it out, it seems to require something that looks like "uniformity" (something that works for all elements in the sum simultaneously), which I don't think I'm necessarily assuming but I may very well be wrong.

I also tried applying something like Fatou's lemma, but $a_{n,i}$ isn't necessarily positive. I don't assume the existence of a uniform bound, either.

Answer (score 5):

No it is not true. If we take $a_{n,i}=\frac{f(n)}{g(i)}$ for a fast growing $g$ and small growing $f$ (that still diverges to $\infty$), then the desired property does not have to hold.

For example, try $$a_{n,i}=\frac{\sqrt n}{2^i}.$$

Comment: Upon looking at it a little more, I'm not sure I follow why $a_{n,i} = \sqrt{n}/2^i$ works here. My assumption is that $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} a_{n,i} = +\infty$ for all $i$ and $n$. If $i = n$, $\sqrt{n}/2^n \rightarrow 0$.

Comment: @Robert890 $\lim_{n \to \infty} a_{n.i}=\infty$ can only mean that $a_{n,i} \to \infty$ as $n \to \infty$ **for fixed** $i$. You cannot make $i$ dependent on $n$.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't mean to say for all $i$ and $n$, but for all $i \in \{1,2, ... , n\}$. Note that $a_{n,n}$ does appear in the sum for every finite $n$.

Comment: In other words, I'm working with row means of triangular arrays.

Comment: @Robert890 I am confused. Do you want to say that you require that $\lim_{n\to\infty} a_{n, f(n)}=0$ for all $f:\mathbb N\to\mathbb N$ such that $f(n)\le n$ ?

Comment: @Robert890 If that is what you mean then of course the statement in your question is true. Following your approach: Let $f:\mathbb N\to\mathbb N$ be a function such that $\min_{1\le i\le n} a_{n,i}=a_{n,f(n)}$ for all $n$. Then by assumption $a_{n,f(n)}$ goes to $\infty$ as $n\to\infty$.